# How to add delete button to a column using JS?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have experience with PHP and HTML, but I am unfamiliar with JS. I have all the code needed, but I can't put it together. I have a table and need to add a delete button that will remove the file on that row. As shown in the picture below, but without the edit button:

[image: delete button on table row]

When click on the Search button, the table is displayed (here is where I need the delete button):

[image: where I need the delete button]

index.php

```
<div style="clear:both; margin-bottom: 10px"></div>
<input type='button' class='button right-button' value='Search' onclick='Search(); return false;'/>
<div style="clear:both; margin-bottom: 10px"></div>

<fieldset id="data-set-fs" style="width:93%; padding-top: 10px; display:none">
<legend>Data Set</legend>
<div id="imported-set-wrapper"></div>
</fieldset>
```

main.js

```
function Search(){

var crop = $("#crop").val();
var type = $("#type").val();
var year = $("#year").val();
var season = $("#season").val();
var location = $("#location").val();
var subLocation = $("#sublocation").val();

$("#imported-set-wrapper").html("");
$("#imported-list-wrapper").html("");
$("#processing").show();

$.ajax({
url: "Resources/PHP/Search.php",
dataType: 'text',
data: {
crop: crop,
type: type,
year: year,
location: location,
season: season,
sublocation: subLocation
},

success: function(response) {
var data = JSON.parse(response);
var items = "";
var firstSet = 0;
if (data.length > 0)
{
var table = "<table id='imported-set-table'>" +

    "<thead>" +
    "<tr>" + 
        //added 
        "<th>Delete</th>" + 
        //added 
        "<th>Year</th>" +
        "<th>Season</th>" +
        "<th>Crop</th>" +
        "<th>Type</th>" +
        "<th>Location</th>" +
        "<th>Sub-location</th>" +
        "</tr>" +
    "</thead>" +
    "<tbody id='imported-set'>" +
    "</tbody>" +
    "</table>";

$("#imported-set-wrapper").html(table);
$.each(data,function(index,item)
{
if (index == 0){
firstSet = item.ID;
}

items+= "<tr id='data-set-" + item.ID + "' onclick='SelectDataSet(\"" + item.ID + "\"); return false;' style='cursor:pointer'>" +
    //added 
    "<td style='overflow:hidden'>" +
        "<span>" + item.Year + "</span>" +
        "</td>" + 
    //added

    "<td style='overflow:hidden'>" +
        "<span>" + item.Year + "</span>" +
        "</td>" +

    "<td style='overflow:hidden'>" +
        "<span>" + item.Season + "</span>" +
        "</td>" +

    "<td style='overflow:hidden'>" +
        "<span>" + item.Crop + "</span>" +
        "</td>" +

    "<td style='overflow:hidden'>" +
        "<span>" + item.Type + "</span>" +
        "</td>" +

    "<td style='overflow:hidden'>" +
        "<span>" + item.Location + "</span>" +
        "</td>" +

    "<td style='overflow:hidden'>" +
        "<span>" + item.SubLocation + "</span>" +
        "</td>" +

    "</tr>";
});

$("#imported-set").html(items);
var rowHeight = 61;
var padding = 10;
var actualHeight = (data.length + 1) * rowHeight + padding;
var maxHeight = 300;
var height = actualHeight < maxHeight ? actualHeight : maxHeight;

$('#imported-set-table').fxdHdrCol({
fixedCols: 0,
width: 1100,
height: height,

colModal: [ 
//added 
{ width: 150, align: 'center' }, 
//added 
{ width: 150, align: 'center' },
{ width: 150, align: 'center' },
{ width: 150, align: 'center' },
{ width: 250, align: 'center' },
{ width: 175, align: 'center' },
{ width: 150, align: 'center' },
],

sort: false
});

if (firstSet > 0){
$("#next").prop("disabled", false);
SelectDataSet(firstSet);
$("#data-set-fs").show();
} else {
alert("No dataset found");
}
}

$("#processing").hide();
},

error: function(xhr){
alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' ' + xhr.responseText);
$("#processing").hide();
}
});
}
```

Useful code from picture 1

```
"<input id='delete-" + type + "-" + item.ID +"' type='image' class='image-button delete-button' src='Resources/Images/delete.png' alt='Delete' onclick='Delete(" + item.ID +", \"" + type + "\"); return false;' title='Delete'>" +
"<input id='confirmDelete-" + type + "-"  + item.ID +"' type='image' class='image-button confirm-delete-button' src='Resources/Images/confirm.png' alt='Confirm' style='display:none' onclick='ConfirmDelete(" + item.ID +", \"" + type + "\"); return false;' title='Confirm'>" +
"<input id='cancelDelete-" + type + "-"  + item.ID +"' type='image' class='image-button cancel-delete-button' src='Resources/Images/cancel.png' alt='Cancel' style='display:none' onclick='CancelDelete(" + item.ID +", \"" + type + "\"); return false;' title='Cancel'>" +

function Delete(id, type){
    $('#confirmDelete-' + type + '-'  + id).show();
    $('#cancelDelete-' + type + '-'  + id).show();
    $('#delete-' + type + '-'  + id).hide();
    CancelEdit(id);
}

function CancelDelete(id, type){
    $('#confirmDelete-' + type + '-'  + id).hide();
    $('#cancelDelete-' + type + '-'  + id).hide();
    $('#delete-' + type + '-'  + id).show();
}

function ConfirmDelete(id, type){


    $.ajax({
        url: 'Resources/PHP/' + type + '.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: { id: id, action: 'delete'},
        success: function(response) {
            if (response == "1") {
                $('#confirmDelete-' + type + '-'  + id).hide();
                $('#cancelDelete-' + type + '-'  + id).hide();
                $('#delete-' + type + '-'  + id).show();

                alert("The " + type + " has been deleted.");

                GetList(type);

            } else {
                alert("Could not delete the " + type + ". Error: " + response + ".");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Additional info: "//added" are additional lines trying to achieve mentioned goal.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  add your button like this `"<button data-id = " + item.ID + " class='delete'>Delete</button>"` where `data-id` has your `item.ID` value this will get passed to your backend to perform delete operation.

Then , when delete button get clicked this `$(document).on("click", ".delete",..` will get called you can show confirm-box so if user click `ok` then call your ajax to delete that `trs` data using `selector.closest('tr').remove()` where `selector` refer to the button which has been clicked .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//dummy datas
var data = [{
  "Year": "2016",
  "Season": "somehting",
  "Crop": "12",
  "Type": "A",
  "Location": "India",
  "SubLocation": "Sub",
  "ID": "1"
}, {
  "Year": "2017",
  "Season": "somehting",
  "Crop": "12",
  "Type": "A",
  "Location": "India",
  "SubLocation": "Sub",
  "ID": "2"
}]

function Search() {
  //some codes..
  $("#imported-set-wrapper").html("");
  $("#imported-list-wrapper").html("");
  $("#processing").show();
  //other codes...
  var table = "<table id='imported-set-table'>" +

    "<thead>" +
    "<tr>" +
    //added 
    "<th>Delete</th>" +
    //added 
    "<th>Year</th>" +
    "<th>Season</th>" +
    "<th>Crop</th>" +
    "<th>Type</th>" +
    "<th>Location</th>" +
    "<th>Sub-location</th>" +
    "</tr>" +
    "</thead>" +
    "<tbody id='imported-set'>" +
    "</tbody>" +
    "</table>";
  var items = "";
  $("#imported-set-wrapper").html(table);
  $.each(data, function(index, item) {
    if (index == 0) {
      firstSet = item.ID;
    }

    items += "<tr id='data-set-" + item.ID + "' onclick='' style='cursor:pointer'>" +

      "<td style='overflow:hidden'>" +
      //added button with data-* attribute
      "<button data-id = " + item.ID + " class='delete'>Delete</button>" +
      "</td>" +

      "<td style='overflow:hidden'>" +
      "<span>" + item.Year + "</span>" +
      "</td>" +

      "<td style='overflow:hidden'>" +
      "<span>" + item.Season + "</span>" +
      "</td>" +

      "<td style='overflow:hidden'>" +
      "<span>" + item.Crop + "</span>" +
      "</td>" +

      "<td style='overflow:hidden'>" +
      "<span>" + item.Type + "</span>" +
      "</td>" +

      "<td style='overflow:hidden'>" +
      "<span>" + item.Location + "</span>" +
      "</td>" +

      "<td style='overflow:hidden'>" +
      "<span>" + item.SubLocation + "</span>" +
      "</td>" +

      "</tr>";
  });

  $("#imported-set").html(items);
  //soem ot//other codes..
}
//onclick of delete button
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id'); //get id
  var selector = $(this);
  console.log(id)
  //show confirm box if yes
  if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    //ajax call
    /*$.ajax({
          url: 'url',
          dataType: 'text',
          data: { id: id, action: 'delete'},
          success: function(response) {
              if (response == "1") {*/
    selector.closest('tr').remove() //remove tr
    /* } else {
                alert("Could not delete the " + type + ". Error: " + response + ".");
            }
        }
    });*/
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="clear:both; margin-bottom: 10px"></div>
<input type='button' class='button right-button' value='Search' onclick='Search(); return false;' />
<div style="clear:both; margin-bottom: 10px"></div>

<fieldset id="data-set-fs" style="width:93%; padding-top: 10px;">
  <legend>Data Set</legend>
  <div id="imported-set-wrapper"></div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you have:

```
//added 
    "<td style='overflow:hidden'>" +
        "<span>" + item.Year + "</span>" +
        "</td>" + 
//added
```

Doesn't this need to be the button? E.g.

```
<td><button onclick='deleteFunction(item.id)'>Delete</button></td>
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: The question is very vague, it's answering where the delete button should be.

Comment: That should be a comment then, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your input @LeeTaylor extremely helpful.

Comment: Since it is JS. I replaced with ```"<td>\n" +
                        "<button onClick='deleteFunction(item.id)'>Delete</button>\n" +
                        "</td>"``` and button is not shown.